# CMD: How to write/print result of java -version to some file

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I try to execute:

```
    cmd /c java -version > someFile.txt
    cmd /c echo java -version > someFile.txt
```

But nothing is written to the file I'm redirecting to.

Answer (score 3):

Capture stderr instead of stdout:

```
java -version 2> someFile.txt
java -fullversion 2> someFile.txt
cmd /c java -version 2> someFile.txt
```

[This](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4380614) explains why Java writes the help to stderr:

> We should think very, very carefully before ever fixing this bug. 
>   It's obviously the wrong thing to print version information to stderr,
>   but since we've been doing that since the beginning of time it seems
>   likely that we'll break existing systems built on top of Java if we
>   change it now.  If we do decide to change this then it must wait until
>   the Tiger release so that adequate testing can be done.

Comment: java -version outputs on stderr. That's just how it's written.

Comment: @wero. turns java use  stderr  to print -version. Did you know, why java this doing?

Comment: @LoKa Because of that quote. As to why in the beginning? You'd have to ask some Pretty Old Java-the-Language devs.

Answer (score 1):

Java writes this information to Standard Error not Standard Output so you need to redirect the correct channel

```
cmd /c java -version 2> someFile.txt
```

This works.